# How can I check the presence of a character in a list of strings and return a specific value?

Tags: python

I need to check if a specific character is present in every list of strings that is nested in another list, and, based on this information return me a number (1,2,3 or 4). The number indicates the presence of this character in a specific string of every list.

So this is a part of my (long) list

```
 mylist = [['m ˈ a n'],
 ['ʔ ˈ aɪ ', ' n ɐ'],
 ['ɡ ˈ ɔ t'],
 ['ɡ l ˈ aʊ ', ' b ə'],
 ['f ˈ aː ', ' t ɐ'],
 ['j ˈ eː ', ' m a n t'],
 ['f r ˈ ɔʏ n t'],
 ['m ˈ o ', ' m ɛ n t'],
 ['h ˈ ɛɐ'],
 ['ʔ ˈ aː ', ' b ə n t'],
 ['h ˈ a l t'],
 ['j ˈ ʊ ŋ ', ' ə'],
 ['b r ˈ uː ', ' d ɐ'],
 ['z ˈ oː n'],
 ['k ˈ ɔ p f'],
 ['d ˈ a ŋ k'],
 ['f ˈ ɪ l m'],
 ['f ˈ a l']]
```

and I want to know if the character `"ˈ"`, which indicates the accent of a specific word is present in syllable number 1,2,3, or 4. (In the example here you see a maximum of 2 syllables, so the result should be 1 or 2, but in the entire list there can be also three or four syllables).

Is there a simple way to check this character in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had misunderstood your question. So you can use a list `pos_lst` to store the string numbers, like this:

```py
pos_lst = []
for sub_l in mylist:
    i = None
    for c, syl in enumerate(sub_l):
        if "ˈ" in syl:
            i = c; break
    pos_lst.append(c+1) # because list indices start from 0, not 1
print(pos_lst)
```

Note that if multiple sub-string contain the character, this will give the last sub-string that contains the character.
Output in this case is:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I use .count() it olnly tells me whether the accent is present in a sublist, which is (almost) always true

Comment: @tor_sten20 can it be present in multiple syllables?

Comment: Not in the same word, or better, not in more than one string in the same sublist

Answer (score 0):

you can this :

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = [['m ˈ a n'],['f ˈ a l']]
x = "ˈ"
for i in range(len(mylist)):
     d = Counter(mylist[i])
     print(d)
```

output:

```
Counter({'m ˈ a n': 1})
Counter({'f ˈ a l': 1})
```